# Prevent sequelize to drop database in node.js app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

First of all, I am using node.js with sequelize ORM and Postgres SQL.

I have 2 simple questions:

1. Every time I rerun my node application sequelize is dropping and creating all tables in database. How to prevent it from doing that (I don't want my records in database to be deleted)? I have tried to set my NODE_ENV to test but it didn't help.
2. How does sequelize migration knows where it stopped (which migration have executed and which not). 
   When I was using database migration in Grails framework, for example, it automatically created a table in the database where it kept all migration timestamps that executed before and when I rerun my application it looks at that table and knows which migrations are already done and which are not. 
   I don't see any table when using node/sequelize, so how it works? :)

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Can you include some code? I'm using sequelize with postgresql and haven't had that problem.

Comment: I copied they express example on sequelize.js web page and only put postgre database instead of mysql (like they did in example) https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-expressjs-example  (link of their example)

Comment: I figured out. They put sync: { force: true } in some part of code in app.js and that override my sync (false) that I defined when connecting to database...now second question is all that bothers me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you already figured out, the tables are being dropped because you are doing

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true })
```

The force true part being the culprit

To your second question - the state of migrations is saved in a table in your db - i believe it's called `sequelize_meta`